# How to pause the execution of Javascript without making a browser lag out?

Tags: javascript

I have a script that changes some values and clicks some buttons in a browser. I'm looking for a way to pause the execution of the code for x seconds without making the browser lag out. I'm using Firefox and I paste this script into its console. I'm aware of the **setTimeout()** function. However, this function doesn't stop executing the code, but rather waits x seconds till executing it. I'm looking for a complete solution that's similar to **Python's time.sleep()** function and pauses the execution of the code completely.

```
var init = 0.01
var start = init
var $odds = $("#oddsOverUnder")
var $button = $("#roll")
var $bet = $("#bet")

function roll(){
    $bet.val(start)
    $button.click()
    //i want to pause the execution of the code here//
    $button.click()
    //and here//
    refreshIntervalId=setInterval(roll2, 2000)}

function roll2(){
    var tr = document.querySelector("#myBetsTable tr:nth-child(2)")
    var cls = tr.getAttribute('class')
    if (cls === 'success'){
        start = init
        $bet.val(start)}
    else{
        start = start * 2
        $bet.val(start)
        $odds.click()}

clearInterval(refreshIntervalId)
roll()}

roll()
```

Comment: have you tried setInterval?

Comment: "The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds)." which doesn't really help me solve my problem.

Comment: well, you could keep track of how many intervals have passed and then clear the interval...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no equivalent to Python's `time.sleep()` in JavaScript, which generally executes asynchronously by design. If you'd like to delay execution of code, you can use `setTimeout`, as you mentioned.

Without understanding exactly what your code is supposed to do, I can't suggest the ideal architecture for this problem. There's definitely a better way to do it than what I'm about to suggest. Still, to answer your question, you can simulate what you're asking this way:

```
function roll() {

    $bet.val(start);
    $button.click();

    setTimeout(function () {
        $button.click();
        setTimeout(function () {
           refreshIntervalId = setInterval(roll2, 2000);
        }, 1000);
    }, 1000);

}
```

Comment: I've chosen this answer because it's explained better than others, thanks for that, it works!

Answer (score 1):

How about setting timeouts inside a timeout?

```
function roll() {
    $bet.val(start)
    $button.click()
    setTimeout(function() {
            $button.click();
            setTimeout(
                function() {
                    $button.click();
                    refreshIntervalId = setInterval(roll2, 2000)
                },
                5000
            );
        },
        5000
    );
}
```

also, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/951057/2119863

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for that and for the link provided above, it's worth reading